SymPy yields a limit 0 for an expression whose limit does not exist
Here is the code.
from sympy import symbols, limit

# Define the variables
x, y = symbols('x y')

# Define the function
f = (x**2 * y) / (x**4 + y**2)   

# Calculate the limit of the function as (x, y) approaches (0, 0)
limit_value = f.limit(x,0).limit(y,0)

print("The limit of the function as (x, y) approaches (0, 0) is:", limit_value)

It prints "0".
The limit does not exist. If you choose the path (t,t) it goes to 0, but if you choose the path (t,t^2) it goes to 1/2.   You can try in
WolframAlpha

You're not calculating the limit as (x, y) approaches (0, 0). You're pointwise calculating the limit as x approaches zero, and then taking that function (0) and calculating the limit as y approaches 0. WolframAlpha agrees that that limit is 0

f.limit(x, 0) already returns 0 (which WolframAlpha agrees with), so the limit of that is naturally 0 as well. Your approach for calculating the multi-variable limit doesn't work as intended.

@Brian61354270: Here is a copy paste from WolframAlpha:  (limit does not exist)
(value may depend on x, y path in complex space).   Now, you are right. The limit should be computed at once for both x and y, but SymPy, apparently does not know how to do that.
